# UWP webview navigates to a URI and it prompts a message to find app in the store to open it, but this is not URI that should open app

Tags: c#, windows, webview, uri, uwp

how to tell webview that the URI it will navigate is not supposed to make it open an app, I use an online payment system by webview and at the end of payment it navigates to something like this "ticketscheme://{"status":"FAILED", "transaction_id":"*********", "result":"FAILED","message":"Payment Declined"}"" so I should get this URI to convert to object to detect if the payment finished OK or it failed but when webview navigates to this it prompts a message 
[image]

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'm facing the same problem right now.

Comment: No I have not unfortunately... And I am still looking for solution. If you find it pleas email me: giga.bokuchava@hotmail.com

Comment: kindly refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43065107/uwp-webview-navigationstarting-event-handler-is-not-working-when-url-is-not-vali) link, it works with my problem

Comment: Thanks. Can you get the URI that was requested as a string value in your case?

Comment: Yup, use this code

 `private static void webView_OnUnsupportedUriSchemeIdentified(WebView sender, WebViewUnsupportedUriSchemeIdentifiedEventArgs args)
        {
            var url = args.Uri.ToString();`

Comment: Thanks but it does not work for me, because my Uri is in wrong format. I am happy that it works for you

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to monitor the [WebView.NavigationStarting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigationstarting.aspx) event ?

It should be raised before any navigation. You should be able to intercept it, check the target URI using [WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs.Uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webviewnavigationstartingeventargs.uri.aspx) and [cancel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webviewnavigationstartingeventargs.cancel.aspx) the navigation if needed.

```
<WebView NavigationStarting="OnNavigationStarting" />


void OnNavigationStarting(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
{
    var url = args.Uri; 
    if(url.Scheme == "myprotocol") 
    {
        // navigating to my custom uri, cancelling...
        args.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that it doesnt invoke that event, because the uri is broken and could not be parsed, but i need that broken uri but i cant get it.

Comment: I listen to WebView.UnsupportedUriSchemeIdentified event and it gets invoke but somehow its event argument is under exception... how to say, it's argument should keep URI but becuase uri is not normal, it cant parse so I cant get uri