# UWP Webview NavigationStarting event handler is not working when URL is not Valid

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, uwp

Subscribe `EvenHandler`:

```
wv.NavigationStarting += webView_NavigationStarting;
```

`EvenHandler` Implementation

```
private static void webView_NavigationStarting(object sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
{
    var url = args.Uri.AbsoluteUri.Substring(args.Uri.AbsoluteUri.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    int parameterCount = url.Split('_').Length;
}
```

When URL is valid it navigates perfectly fine, otherwise `EvenHandler` was not called.

And the pop up below shows:

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of a bad URL?

Comment: `<a href="page:MyPage_3252">My Page</a>` like this one, I need to parse the href first that's why I'm calling NavigationStarting EventHandler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [WebView.UnsupportedUriSchemeIdentified](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_WebView_UnsupportedUriSchemeIdentified) event to handle unknown uri's.

```cs
private void webView_OnUnsupportedUriSchemeIdentified(WebView sender, WebViewUnsupportedUriSchemeIdentifiedEventArgs args)
{
    args.Handled = true;

    // up to you what to do with args.Uri
}
```

Be aware that if the link is invalid, the `WebView.NavigationFailed` will be raised instead!

Comment: Works fine with my problem :) Thanks,